# How to calculate gas fee for transaction?

Tags: gas, fee

I want to calculate three gas fees (low, average, fast) for transactions in the Tezos blockchain,Is there any formula to calculate gas fees for every transaction?

I want to do an operation on the Tezos blockchain, So I want to know the minimum gas fee to do the operation! after that, when I know the minimum gas fee to succeed in the operation, I can increase the minimum gas fee to calculate the average, and the fast gas fee depends on the minimum gas fee

Comment: `(low, average, fast)` with respect to what? I see for instance. `low`: so that a baker would include the tx, `fast`: the tx would be included in the next block, by taking into account the current operations/fees in the mempool ...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at file [estimate.ts](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/blob/master/packages/taquito/src/estimate/estimate.ts#L51) in the taquito repository.

The base value is what you call `low`, from there you just need to define some thresholds for `average` and `fast`.

Also remember, there is a storage burn that may occur depending on the storage diff of your operations and is not part of the fee.